# Load images based on URL in Wordpress

Tags: php, image, wordpress

I need to load images based on the end of a URL onto a page, instead of going into 100s of pages and manually entering the image code. The way it would work would be

PSUEDO CODE EXAMPLE:

```
IF url EQUALS folder name (where images are stored)
  Load images from that folder
END IF
```

For example the code would search for the folder xt660z, based on the URL http://a2.mattmaclennan.co.uk/new_bikes/xt660z/

Any ideas? I would have asked on the Wordpress area, but I'm thinking this is more PHP.

P.S: I know how to load things based on an ID in a URL, not sure if it is the same principle?

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "Load?" Do you mean just generate an img tag?

Comment: That's right yes, will try your answer out when I'm at a computer, thanks! :)

Comment: Awesome! If you have any questions or trouble post it here and I'll see if I can help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're just wanting to generate an img tag for each file in one of your template directories this should do the trick:

```
<?php
$url=$_SERVER[‘REQUEST_URI’];
$url_parts = explode('/',$url);
end($url_parts);
$dir = current($url_parts)=='' ? prev($url_parts) : current($url_parts);
$dir = {get_template_directory_uri()} . '/' . $dir;
if (is_dir($dir)) {
    foreach(scandir($dir) as $file) {
        if(! is_dir($dir . '/' . $file)) {
            echo '<img src=' . $dir . '/' . $file ' />';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Note that there's no handling in here whatsoever, so if your url is not a directory then you get nothing, and if your directory has files in it that are not images then you will get broken image tags.